# In Texmaker's built-in viewer, can I open a PDF file other than the one I'm writing at that moment?

Tags: texmaker, viewers

Example:

I make translation of science papers now, and it would be SUPER COMFORTABLE if I can open an article in the built-in PDF viewer, look and translate it into another language.

I hope my request is understandable, English is not my native language.

Comment: you can use the user commands menu i.e. define a command that view static .pdf file.

Comment: Could u please give me example?

Comment: go to menu `User-->Use commands-->Edit user commands` type your command (you can use the wizard)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about such a feature in Texmaker, but, you can open the page of the original file you are translating at the moment just below where you are writing using the `pdfpages` package like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

Here, I am writing my translation ..

and just below it, the corresponding page(s) in the original file.
\includepdf[pages=<specify>]{original.pdf}

\end{document}
```